# Weird usb error shows up during ubuntu 20.04 hibernation

Tags: usb, 20.04, hibernate

My pc used to have no issues during hibernation in ubuntu 19.10. But after upgrading to 20.04 today at first the hibernation was not working then i replaced the lines in here

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

with this

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-
key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-m$
ResultActive=yes
```

replacing this

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

but after that i see this weird lines going very fast, like a loop during hibernating just before power going down.

```
[365.some_random_number] usb 3-1: clear tt 1 (9042) error -71
```

attached [see this mobile camera shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g337u.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran these two command and rebooted, then seems like the resolved is resolved for now. may be it was a outdated firmware issue

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
```